# How to associate a app.manifest with a Windows Store 8.1 Project

Tags: windows-store-apps, manifest, appxmanifest

My Visual studio project only has only a Package.appxmanifest but I need to add  to the app.manifest.

It is straight forward to add the app manifest and this setting but how do you tell the app to use it?

In older projects you would go into project properties but this only lists the appxmanifest which is a different structure

Comment: What is in you app.manifest file that you can't find in the Package.appxmanifest file?

Comment: Hi James - just noticed this.   I need to set UI access = true because I am having problems with User Interface Privilege Isolation and sendInput

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Package.appxmanifest was the new implementation for the app manifest and adding the old manifest file will have no impact on the application.

Comment: Thank you for for that - I kind of guessed that would be the case and Its great that you have given me the time to confirm this.  Very much appreciated